# ProcessBuilder does not display command window

Tags: java

I am trying to run a .bat file from my java code and I'm using the ProcessBuilder.java functionality as follows:

```
    String[] hubCmd = new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "startHub.bat"};
    ProcessBuilder pbHub = new ProcessBuilder(hubCmd);
    pbHub.directory(new File("C:\\java\\selenium\\"));
    Process hubP = pbHub.start();
```

This seems to work, kicks of a java process and associated cmd process, but the command window is not displayed.  Am I missing something or is this correct functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like correct functionality to me

Comment: why do you want it to open command window ? just to see logs ? if so you can actually stream back the  output of that process

Comment: Admittedly an element of laziness, although I do need to sort out logging the output.  But still, just a bit annoying that there is no switch to tell it to actually display the cmd window.

Comment: Even if you opened one CMD window on your Windows machine, you can start other CMD processes (inside) which won't open other windows.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start");` this probably should display the command window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's Process is meant to execute a command, and so it does with cmd.exe.

What you see is correct. cmd.exe does not have a "feature" for displaying a window.

The "window" you normally see is a terminal emulation or some such thing which in turn (like your Java program!) can execute another program, i.e., cmd.exe

It is the same with Linux, where an xterm executes a shell (the command interpreter). No shell (in the classic style) can display a "window".

You can make your Java program the "window"!